# My player disappears when launching my 2D Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a 2d platformer game in Unity 5 following these tutorials: https://www.3dbuzz.com/training/view/creating-2d-games-in-unity-45

I am however running into a problem where when I hit the play button in Unity my character simply does not appear inside the game. I made sure he is on the right layer and has all of the required scrips associated to him and still no dice...

Here is a copy of my source code: https://mega.co.nz/#!4YFAVLxA!8UZieNrqI3F1--4HsaLPPfw_ICbCkG7uGZVuWAfmSyY

Comment: In order for people to be abel to help you on this site, you need to reduce the code to a short self-contained example that reproduced the problem, and post the code in the body of the question (links to an offline-hosted zip file are neither useful to current answerers nor future visitors). You should also ndicate what you've already tried and how it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue was that my main camera was not far enough on the Z axis and unity was rendering my player behind the camera!

I fixed it by setting the camera's Z coordinate to -100 instead on -10.